# Is it possible to force user to select at least one option in AlertDialog setMultiChoiceItems()?

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment, multichoiceitems

I have a `DialogFragment` that displays three options to the user and a positive button. The dialog works as a filter, so the user can check all options, two or one, and based on that, I show some items or others.

Currently, it works, but also the user can uncheck all choices and tap on the apply button, making my `Fragment` to do not display any item. I would like to show a message to the user before this happens, warning him/she that at least 1 option must be checked, and hence, avoiding the dialog to be closed until the user dismisses the dialog or checks at least one choice and tap accept.

This is my code:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.filter_title));
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(this.choices, this.selection,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, boolean b) {
                    changeSelection(i, b);
                }
            });
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.filter_accept, 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            listener.onDialogPositiveClick(ListItemsFragment.this);
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If the box can be dismissed them you can as well allow none selected and if determined none do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you've shared, I don't really know what the function `changeSelection(..)` is doing, or how are you handling responses from your multi choice listener.

Nevertheless, I think that inside the positive button's click listener callback, you should check that any value inside your `this.selection` boolean array is currently `true`, and only move forward if that's the case. The `selector` array should be getting updated on the `MultiChoiceItems` listener, and this should enable you to operate based on the present data at all times.

In short, I would try to do something like:

```java
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.filter_title));
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(this.choices, this.selection,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int index, boolean isChecked) {
                    // Keep track of the selected items
                    selection[index] = isChecked;
                }
            });
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.filter_accept, 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            for (boolean isSelected : selection) {
                if (isSelected) {
                    // Found at least one selected option -- carry on
                    listener.onDialogPositiveClick(ListItemsFragment.this);
                } else {
                    // Unable to find not a single selected option
                    //TODO: Handle not having a single option selected
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Where the MultiChoiceItems selector is constantly keeping track of the latests selections (you may already be doing this inside `changeSelection(..)`), and you don't let the positive button click advance unless we can confirm that there is indeed at least one item currently selected.

Comment: Hi, this is my idea, but my problem is that I do not know what code should I add in "//TODO: Handle not having a single option selected". This is the code I need help with. How can I avoid the Dialog to be closed there?

Comment: I think the code as-is should already work for your case -- have you tried it?  The TODO was added to do any post-processing functionality, like showing a toast letting the User know to select at least one option, or displaying some kind of error message in the Dialog itself. Nevertheless, the for-loop + if-statement inside the click listener are already checking if there are options selected, and only calling onto the Dialog's positive click listener if that's the case.